# Complex AR query, where clause one column equal to another column's value?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've written up the AR query below, but have one problem with a where clause.  On the `Payout` model there is a `comp_builder_id` and there's also a `comp_builder_id` on a `ContractLevel`.

I want to add a where clause to this query to get the data where the `Payout` model's `comp_builder_id` is equal to the `ContractLevel` model's `comp_builder_id`.

```
payouts = Payout.includes(:comp_builder => { 
                                    :contract_levels => { 
                                        :transmittal => [
                                            {:appointment_hierarchies => :child}, 
                                            :appointment_cases
                                        ] 
                                    } 
                                })
                                .includes(:product)
                                .includes(:payor)
                                .where(products: { :id => self.product.id })
                                .where(appointment_cases: { :case_id => self.id })
                                .where(transmittals: { :id => appointment_case.transmittal_id })
                                .where(contract_levels: { :transmittal_id => appointment_case.transmittal_id, 
                                                          :appointment_id => Transmittal.find(appointment_case.transmittal_id).low,
                                                          :comp_builder_id => # ? payout's comp builder id ?  })
```

How can this be done in Active Record?  In the last few where clauses I'm referencing different variables, those can be ignored as this query is just a snippet.

Comment: Similar to how in MySQL I can run a query like `select * from users where users.child_id = users.parent_id` and it doesn't interpret parent_id as a value but looks at the column in the table.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass a string into the where statement:

```
User.include(:parent).where('users.parent_id = parents.id')
```

Basically if you know what you want the where statement to look like in raw SQL then you can just pass it in as a string into the where statement.

That is the only way I know of to make complex where statements in ActiveRecord.

Just make sure to remember that you need to reference the column names, not the model names.

Comment: There's no way to do this in Active Record?

Comment: Not that I know of